# Expected value of re-flipping a coin

Tags: probability, expected-value, game-theory

This is a simplification and slight modification of an interview question which I found online.

**Quesiton**: You flip 3 coins and if you get HHH or TTT you will win \$X. How much are you willing to pay for this game?
**Solution:** Since my chances of winning is $\frac{1}{4}$, I would pay \$$\frac{X}{4}$ to play this game.

**Follow Up 1**: What if you can have an option to re-flip any of the coins? 
**Solution**: I still have $\frac{1}{4}$ chances of winning plus for any other outcomes I have $\frac{1}{2}$ chances of winning, so I am willing to pay \$$\frac{3*X}{4}$ to play this game.

**Follow Up 2**: What if you can re-flip a certain coin, let's say the last one 
**Solution**: I still have $\frac{1}{4}$ chances plus if I get HHT or TTH I will re-flip. The chances I get HHT or TTH is $\frac{1}{4}$ and the chances that I win after re-flipping is $\frac{1}{8}$, so I am willing to pay \$$\frac{3*X}{8}$ to play this game.

Is my logic correct for all the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one and the last one are correct. The second is not correct.

For the second one, there is $\frac{1}{4}$ chance that we get $3H$ or $3T$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ chance that we get $2H, 1T$ or $2T,1H$. Given the option that we can re-flip a coin, we would re-flip the coin that we have one of. So if we had $2H,1T$ and we re-flip the coin that had $T$, there is $\frac12$ chance that we get $H$ and we win $ \$X$. Similarly for the case $2T, 1H$.

So expected win value $ = \displaystyle \left(\frac14 + \frac12 \cdot \frac34 \right) \cdot X = \frac{5X}{8}$.